# OpenLdap setup ldif and ldapmodify

Tags: openldap

Setting up Openldap on E2 instance. 
Need help with ldapmodify and setup.ldif file to modify files

My setup.ldif contained::::

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}BdP7KhrVpogG0RxWvy2111g0cMMSN
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}BdP7KhrVpogG0RxWvy2111g0cMMSN
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=superman,dc=planet,dc=org
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=planet,dc=org
```

Then on server ran

```
ldapmodify -a -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /tmp/setup.ldif
```

When I check below nothing got changed

```
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}hdb.ldif
```

**Background:**

> slappasswd    # to get {SSHA}randomstring
>   Started slapd service

Did the mistake of editing the olcDatabase\={2}hdb.ldif  file without reading the first line to use:  ldapmodify.

Still working and searching internet but any insight is appreciated.. First time posting so formatting might not be the best wrt ldif file and the extra spaces

Comment: Forgot to mention when ran
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=superman,dc=planet,dc=org" -f base.ldif
to setup some OU the computer prompt told me that I was invalid
Hard to argue with a terminal
Was running all commands as:   sudo su -  ... since setting up everything proof of concept

Answer (score 0):

In the LDIF file needed to change a reference in line for bdb to hdb:
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
to be
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config

Good reference is:
https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/step-step-openldap-server-configuration-centos-7-rhel-7.html
Next step to get clients servers ..